# Very low framerate since I switched from Mint to Debian

Tags: debian, nvidia, graphics

I just recently upgraded from Linux Mint to Debian, I haven't had any problems so far except one, I'm developing small games with Love2D and I noticed an absurdly low framerate while it was running perfectly before, I I then did as a test just a small sprite animation on a black background (which would run perfectly fine on Mint or Windows) which runs on Debian at 40 fps... And from there I also noticed that there were some times slight mouse lag when I'm just on Firefox, something that wasn't on Linux Mint.

I first thought it could be because I enabled the `nomodeset` in `/etc/default/grub` but I had also done it on Mint and by disabling it and restarting the problem was still here...

I kept the same environment from Mint to Debian (Mate) the same default driver (Nouveau). I have an Nvidia Quadro NVS 160M on this PC (old I know), I thought of installing the non free driver but the latest compatible one is version 340 and it is no longer maintained and not compatible with kernels higher than the 5.4.

I can't figure out where this problem is coming from...

I ran this command if it helps on the system I have:

```
$ inxi -SMGCx
System:
  Host: Latitude-E6500 Kernel: 5.10.0-18-amd64 x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc 
  v: 10.2.1 Desktop: MATE 1.24.1 Distro: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) 
Machine:
  Type: Portable System: Dell product: Latitude E6500 v: N/A 
  serial: <superuser required> 
  Mobo: Dell model: 0W610R serial: <superuser required> BIOS: Dell v: A29 
  date: 06/04/2013 
CPU:
  Info: Dual Core model: Intel Core2 Duo P8700 bits: 64 type: MCP 
  arch: Penryn rev: A L2 cache: 3 MiB 
  flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 ssse3 bogomips: 10108 
  Speed: 1661 MHz min/max: 800/2535 MHz boost: enabled Core speeds (MHz): 
  1: 1661 2: 1654 
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA G98M [Quadro NVS 160M] vendor: Dell driver: N/A 
  bus ID: 01:00.0 
  Device-2: Microdia Integrated_Webcam_2M type: USB driver: uvcvideo 
  bus ID: 2-6:3 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: nouveau,vesa 
  unloaded: fbdev,modesetting resolution: 1440x900 
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.1 128 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 20.3.5 
  direct render: Yes
```

**UPDATE 1:** *(Still unresolved)* After a lot of research I came across a Reddit post about slowness on Debian and a user advised to replace the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` package with `firmware-misc-nonfree` but it didn't work. not work for me, here's how I went about it:

```
# apt install firmware-misc-nonfree
# apt purge xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

I want to specify in case it helps someone that you have to activate the non-free repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list` in order to install `firmware-misc-nonfree`.

**UPDATE 2:** *(solved)* My apologies, I was getting so rushed that I was skipping steps, I forgot to do an `update-grub` after re-editing `/etc/default/grub` and the problem was indeed with the `nomodeset` option , the other problem is that it saved me from having freezes, so I will have to find another more technical solution for my old graphics card...

I still wonder why the `nomodeset` is so much slower on Debian than on Mint in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten to say that the problem was still solved although another solution should be possible, I finally opted to install a distribution with a 5.4 kernel because it is the latest to fully support the NVidia driver proprietary 340, the distribution I opted for is therefore a Linux Mint 20.3 which will be supported until 2025.